# How can I build a web interface on top of hundreds of excel reports

Tags: python, rest, web-services, elasticsearch

I have a large document collection on Excel financial reports. These reports are sitting on a shared drive and not all users have access to the drive. I would like to build some form of basic web interface with search capabilities so user can see the data.

I have jupyter notebook running on my machine that can connect to the files. My questions are:
 1. How can I build a web interface where the user can search for a customer that will trigger a function in the jupyter notebook. The function will bring back customer data and display on the browser.

2. Since the purpose is to mostly do search and not any calculations, should I forget about python completely and look at elastic search? How can I get started with a basic elastic search query? Or is something like Cassandra better?

I need the search to go across multiple excel files and bring back all results. So if we search for customer 'ABC', it will get me monthly stats for the last 12 months (each month is stored in a separate excel file).

Answer (score 1):

In order to make excel data searchable you would need to have some sort of script which reads these excel files and then uses the elasticsearch [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk) to index these excel sheets. Since you mentioned you are using python you could also use elasticsearch-py for this purpose and use the API they expose ([Bulk helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers))

Depending on how you indexed these excel files into elasticsearch documents you would then probably either do a full text search using `query_string` or something or use a `match` (or even `match_phrase`)query (if you have some specific search analyzer you would like to use) to search these documents. Check all the options here ([full text search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html)). For searching you could either use http calls ([Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)) or use some type of client to do this, like [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html).

A simple query could probably look something like this

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "customer",
            "query" : "Akzo Nobel"
        }
    }
}
```

Which you would post to your index containing your document.

NOTE: Elasticsearch is very fast for searching but is less well versed when it comes to document retrieval. This will not be an issue however unless you are retrieving thousands upon thousands of documents. Even if you are planning on doing something like the aforementioned, you could always still use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#search-request-scroll) of Elasticsearch

EDIT: Since I saw you mention metrics you could also have a look at [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) and use that to create dashboards where you show different metrics of your customers. This could possibly save you time or the need to even create a complete web interface and it's completely open source. You read more on how to use Kibana with your elasticsearch instance here: [Kibana docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.4/setup.html)

Comment: Thank you. Will Elastic Search also help in building out the UI  web front end ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Elasticsearch is just a piece of software written in Java, a search engine.  You can build any type of web interface and query elasticsearch through basic HTTP calls. You can use any tech stack on your backend that will allow for HTTP calls to be made to your Elasticsearch instance. Most programming languages have a Elasticsearch client library that will help you do this if you don't want to use plain HTTP calls, have a look at this page to get an idea https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html

Comment: @Victor Maybe you meant Kibana, see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you, I actually need a UI with a search box and a magnifying glass icon.